# Process Builder - Customize the Logic

Tags: process-builder, business-logic

Can I customize the logic of a process builder as below?

```
(4 AND 1) OR 2 OR 3
```

Comment: Can you please add more information on what you are trying to accomplish? When you say customize, does it mean, optimize the logic into a shorter format?

Comment: In the process builder you have a series of criteria, numbered 1, 2, 3, 4.  If I actually want #4 and #1 to be considered first, can I use (4 AND 1) OR 2 OR 3?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can add this in the process builder.

Attached screen shot for this

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you understood what the question is about?

Comment: @ArnoldJr. I think yes. he is asking for put condition login in process builder.

Comment: Also, will the condition logic in parenthesis be considered first?  Will (4 AND 1) be considered before OR 2 OR 3?

Comment: Yes, this will work as you said